# Has a Poké Ball ever captured anything other than a Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon

It seems such a handy device: a small ball which you throw and somehow captures (or *imprisons*) a sentient being, almost always much larger than the ball, inside.

**Has a Poké ball ever been used to (try to) capture anything other than a Pokémon?**

Does it work? If not, why not?

Comment: This question from Anime & Manga SE might already have the answer to your question: [Are there any other uses for a Pokéball besides capturing and storing Pokemon?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2881/are-there-any-other-uses-for-a-pokeball-besides-capturing-and-storing-pokemon)

Comment: @Scorch91 Sort of, although the answer over there isn't _that_ great.

Comment: @SQB That answer *does* mention that Ash has caught a rice-ball (or "doughnut" in the dub) with a pokeball, which is an instance of someone capturing something other than a pokemon in a pokeball.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ash tries to catch a Mankey in '[Primape goes bananas](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP025)' but inadvertently snares a rice ball.

The Poké Ball appears to successfully digitise it, but then rejects it immediately afterwards.

[image]

Mewtwo's special balls in '[Mewtwo Strikes Back](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon:_The_First_Movie)' are capable of capturing *Poké Balls*, complete with their cargo of Pokémon.

[image]

As can be seen in '[The Tower of Terror](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/EP023)', **you can't catch a human with a standard ball.**

[image]

However, the Pokéstar Studios movie *[Timegate Traveler](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Timegate_Traveler_Series)* is about a future where Bug-type Pokémon now rule the world and keep humans in specially designed *Human Balls*.

Comment: The Bug-type pokemon are sick of being early-game fodder.

Comment: @Parrotmaster well, missingno is a bug found quite late in the first few games...